# How to include background colors while exporting excel without any gems in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I saw this article which gives a simple example on how to export data into Excel sheet without using any gem in Rails:

```
https://makandracards.com/makandra/31567-exporting-to-excel-from-rails-without-a-gem
```

I believe the above article is based on a RailsCast tutorial on the same topic:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast
```

I would like to know how to include background colors and row borders (and also border colors) please. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the "manual" XML approach, a good way to start is an official [Microsoft XML Spreadsheet Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10)).

There are many options available, for example a document with borders may look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Styles> 
      <Style ss:ID="h1" ss:Name="First">
        <Borders>
          <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
        </Borders> 
      </Style>   
  </Styles> 

  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="h1"><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="h1"><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="h1"><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data>    </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="h1"><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

You can define different styles at the beginning of the workbook section and then apply them to different cells.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply! 

I have a couple of more questions on this. I will post them as different questions.

Comment: the cell styles don't work for me - I have posted this as a new question. Pls help!

Comment: @Biju there is no need in new question. I've updated my example with a new code, you need to add style attributes to cells, not data. The fast way to test the properties you need is to just create a simple table with the formatting you need, save it as XML and see the output code.